# 'Three times' and 'a third'

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

We say

> This type of bread has **three times** the calorie content of tortilla.

But how do I say it the other way?

> A tortilla has _____ the calorie content of this type of bread.

Is *'a third the calorie content of___'* even idiomatic or grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "a third the calorie content" is correct; "one third the calorie content" would also be correct.  In English, fractions (like "a third") and multipliers (like "three times") are used as **predeterminers,** meaning that they come before the determiner of the noun that they modify, so in this case they go before the word "the."

Fractions can also be used partitively; you can say "a third of the calorie content." But the "of" is unnecessary here; I wouldn't include it.

Comment: The 'of' is considered necessary by many native speakers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you have a source for that? To me it sounds better without the "of," and Huddleston & Pullum state that it is optional.

Comment: [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+third+the+number%2Cone+third+of+the+number%2Ca+third+the+number%2Ca+third+of+the+number&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests that the partitive is more common in its corpus but both are clearly acceptable.

Comment: It does seem though that in some cases [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+third+the+amount%2Cone+third+of+the+amount%2Ca+third+the+amount%2Ca+third+of+the+amount&year_start=2015&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) accepts this more readily than [BrE.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+third+the+amount%2Cone+third+of+the+amount%2Ca+third+the+amount%2Ca+third+of+the+amount&year_start=2015&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can't you be half the man you used to be?

Comment: @tchrist - you heard about my sawmill accident?